# can anyone give sample code for TabHost in Android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I need sample code to create TabHost in android.
can anyone help me.

Comment: The answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209406/issues-with-android-tabhost-example) list all the issues with the sample code, and the workarounds that people have found.

Comment: this tutorial might help you http://learnncode.wordpress.com/2013/12/18/how-to-use-tabwidget-with-fragments/

Answer (score 7):

The Android Developer site has an excellent fully worked code sample for creating tabs in Android using the `TabWidget` and `TabHost`.

Check out [Hello, TabWidget](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html).

Comment: what drives me nuts about their examples?  That they don't contain all the information necessary.  Take the line 'mTabHost = getTabHost();' for example - there is no prior reference to or description of 'mTabHost'.  And, their other tab example has typo's that stop it from compiling.  And, when it's compiled, it 'core dumps'.

Answer (score 2):

I had done tabhost related code with respect to displaying scores

```
    TabHost host = getTabHost();
    host.setup ();

    TabSpec allScoresTab = host.newTabSpec("allTab");
    allScoresTab.setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.all_scores), getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on));
    allScoresTab.setContent(R.id.ScrollViewAllScores);
    host.addTab(allScoresTab);

    TabSpec friendScoresTab = host.newTabSpec("friendsTab");
    friendScoresTab.setIndicator(getResources().getString(R.string.friends_scores), getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.star_on));
    friendScoresTab.setContent(R.id.ScrollViewFriendScores);
    host.addTab(friendScoresTab);

    host.setCurrentTabByTag("allTab");
```

My xml contains :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bkgrnd">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView_Header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/quizicon"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        </ImageView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/scores"
            android:textSize="@dimen/screen_title_size"
            android:shadowDx="0"
            android:shadowDy="0"
            android:shadowRadius="10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:shadowColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColor="@color/title_color">
        </TextView>
        <ImageView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/ImageView_Header2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/quizicon"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        </ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
   <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollViewAllScores" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scrollbars="vertical">
  <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout_AllScores" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="*" /> 
  </ScrollView>
- <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollViewFriendScores" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:scrollbars="vertical">
  <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayout_FriendScores" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="*" /> 
  </ScrollView>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

activity_main.xml contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/scroll" />

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/tabs_bg" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>

</TabHost>
```

and java code is

```
TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        TabSpec spec;

        Intent intent;

        //Home Tab
        View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.home, null);

        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Firstclass.class);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("HOME").setIndicator(view1)
                .setContent(intent);

        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        //Calendar Tab
        View view2 = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.calendar_tab, null);

        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Calendar.class);

        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("CALENDAR").setIndicator(view2)
                .setContent(intent);

        tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 0):

res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#ffc916"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="This is tab 1" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#da8200"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="This is tab 2" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#5b89ff"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:text="This is tab 3" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

src/MainActivity.java

```
  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TabHost tabHost;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TabHost host = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    host.setup();

    //Tab 1
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab One");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("Tab One");
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab 2
    spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Two");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("Tab Two");
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Tab 3
    spec = host.newTabSpec("Tab Three");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab3);
    spec.setIndicator("Tab Three");
    host.addTab(spec);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

You can Follow these tutorials for help

[Creating a tabbed UI with TabHost](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/tab_layout/walkthrough_creating_a_tabbed_ui/)

[Android Tab Layout Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/08/android-tab-layout-tutorial/)