# TabWidget NullpointerException?

Tags: android, tabwidget

I am trying to create a tab widget with two tabs to open two different activities and written following layout to achieve this but it is giving me a `NullPointerException`.

Where is my mistake?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/tabhost" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
        <TabWidget 
            android:id="@android:id/tabs" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 
        </FrameLayout> 
    </LinearLayout> 
</TabHost>
```

In the Java class which is extending `TabWidget` I have the following code in the `onCreate` method:

```
setContentView(R.layout.more);

TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
mTabHost.setup();

Intent intent;

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Settings.class);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator(
                        "Calculator", 
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab01)).setContent(intent));

intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Post.class);                
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator(
                        "YouTube", 
                        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab02)).setContent(intent));
```

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine your stack trace, which will tell you where your problem is.

Comment: 02-18 11:08:01.197: INFO/ActivityManager(52): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.example.FindItNear/.More }
02-18 11:08:11.224: WARN/ActivityManager(52): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
02-18 11:08:11.368: WARN/ActivityManager(52): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{43dba948 com.example.FindItNear/.More}

Comment: add your comment as an edit to the post (so that it can be formatted and therefore read more easily)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you are extending your tab class using TabActivity then it is must

to use ids of tab related controls like "@android:id/tabhost"

i was using "@+id/tabhost" which is wrong but in case of extending it through Activity class its fine.

and above problem which i was facing on layout will not come...

Tab tutorial was also bit buggy it can be solved using following example.
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209406/issues-with-android-tabhost-example)

Comment: So, have you fixed it or not?