# Color TabWidget

Tags: android

Is there a way that I can color the TabWidget View?  Both the idle and selected colors?  That way my app can look a little more personalized, ya know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can apply any images and colors to it and customize it as you like. See the last comment with code sample from me at [Android TabHost - Activities within each tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103062/android-tabhost-activities-within-each-tab/3103156#3103156)

You can then swap the bg images onTabChanged as you like.