# Exception when use android tabs with intent to start activity

Tags: java, android

I have an error when i use intent to start activity when i choose a tab

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, tab1.class);
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("Search").setContent(intent));
```

the erroe is

```
Sorry !
The Application has stopped unexpectedly  , please try again later
```

Comment: Please post up a logcat error output for that exception and also by convention please name all your classes with a capital.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209406/issues-with-android-tabhost-example) for a possible solution (this seems to be a common TabHost issue)

Answer (score 0):

You've most likely not defined the classes (activities) you are trying to load in your AndroidManifest.xml.