# MonoDroid HelloTabWidget tutorial does not package. 

Tags: java, android, sdk, xamarin.android

We have been able to run and test all the example widgets with monodroid except the hellotabwidget. It fails to package and the error is not presented. Can someone please post a working example of the tab widget or explain what is wrong with the tab tutorial on the monodroid website?  We are using the latest version of monodroid (just released but have not purchased yet)

http://mono-android.net/Tutorials/Hello_Views/Tab_Layout is the link to the tutorial that is not working..... We wrote monodroid and they gave us a way to see the "error" below but this is crazy.

Thanks for any assistance.

Unfortunately, what's happening is that the Android `aapt` tool is reporting an error and `mandroid` isn't properly capturing and reporting that error. :-(

This will be fixed in the next release, but in the meantime here is a (horrible!) sequence of steps to follow to determine the actual error:

1. Open a Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010), hereinafter referred to as the terminal:
   Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 -> Visual Studio Tools -> Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)
2. Within the terminal, navigate to your project directory.
3. Run the following command:

   > MSBUILD /t:Install YOUR.csproj /p:MandroidExtraArgs=-v=10
4. In the voluminous output, you want to look for the line that looks like:

   Running command: E:\Applications\Android\android-sdk-windows.r10\platform-tools\aapt "package" "-f" "-M" "AndroidManifest.xml" "-J" "src" "--custom-package" "p14test.p14test" "-F" "bin\packaged_resources" "-S" "E:\tmp\VSProjects\P14Test\P14Test\obj\Debug\res" "-I" "E:\Applications\Android\android-sdk-window s.r10\platforms\android-8\android.jar"
5. Run the following command:

   > cd obj\Debug\android
6. Execute the command referenced in (4):

   > E:\Applications\Android\android-sdk-windows.r10\platform-tools\aapt "package" "-f" "-M" "AndroidManifest.xml" "-J" "src" "--custom-package" "p14test.p14test" "-F" "bin\packaged_resources" "-S" "E:\tmp\VSProjects\P14Test\P14Test\obj\Debug\res" "-I" "E:\Applications\Android\android-sdk-window s.r10\platforms\android-8\android.jar"

You should now be able to see the lost error message.

Thanks for helping on this....

Answer (score 0):

I've no idea what monodroid is, but it looks like the tutorial is the same as the Android SDK tutorial which is broken. See

[Issues with Android TabHost Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209406/issues-with-android-tabhost-example)

on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You could have made it a lot easier for people to help if you had simply posted the error message you were getting, especially if it is really hard to get.

Regardless, the full code is part of the API Demo sample app, which works on my device:

https://github.com/mono/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ApiDemo/Tutorials/TabLayoutTutorial.cs