# Creating A Fancy UI in Android?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

[image]i tried to create a frame layout in tabhost but that didn't work, is it possible to create framelayout, linear layout and absolutelayout in android? How to create this kind of layout in xml. can anyone guide me or give me a link?

Comment: Don't use `AbsoluteLayout` - ever. It's a bad idea to use absolute positioning when it comes to supporting multiple devices with different screen-specs. And it's deprecated.

Comment: You can try this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to have a framelayout with a linear layout inside, but I don't see the point using absolutlayout in this context.
For the tabhost problem here is a sample code that might help you:

[can anyone give sample code for TabHost in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/954249/can-anyone-give-sample-code-for-tabhost-in-android)

good luck,
Arkde